Kafka Deserialization Error: No type information in headers and no default type provided, Consumer exception
I am encountering a deserialization issue with Kafka in my Spring Boot application. Here are the details:
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordDeserializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition get-orders-amount-0 at offset 6. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No type information in headers and no default type provided

2024-09-16T21:48:08.588+05:00 ERROR 18261 --- [order-service] [ntainer#1-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.CompletedFetch       : [Consumer clientId=consumer-group_id-3, groupId=group_id] Deserializers with error: Deserializers{keyDeserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer@3303c6c0, valueDeserializer=org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer@48b85369}

2024-09-16T21:48:08.588+05:00 ERROR 18261 --- [order-service] [ntainer#1-0-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : Consumer exception


I am creating a project with 5 microservices. Others are running but this particular service is running but it keeps sending errors endlessly.
Kafka Config Class:
package com.daurenassanbaev.orderservice.config;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.*;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, Map<String, Integer>> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, Map<String, Integer>> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }
    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, BigDecimal> amountKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(amountProducerFactory());
    }


    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, BigDecimal> amountProducerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, List<Integer>> listConsumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group_id");
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        configProps.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        configProps.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
        configProps.put(JsonDeserializer.VALUE_DEFAULT_TYPE, List.class.getName());
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

}

application.yaml file:
spring:
  application:
    name: order-service

  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/order_db
    username: postgres
    password: postgres

  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
      properties:
        hibernate:
          dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
          show_sql: true
          format_sql: true

  kafka:
    consumer:
      group-id: group_id
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
      properties:
        spring.kafka.consumer.value-default-type: java.util.List
        spring.kafka.consumer.trusted-packages: "*"

server:
  port: 0

logging:
  file:
    name: /Users/daurenassanbaev/IdeaProjects/e-commerce/order-service/order-service-logs.log


Service
package com.daurenassanbaev.orderservice.service;

import com.daurenassanbaev.orderservice.database.entity.Order;
import com.daurenassanbaev.orderservice.database.repository.OrderRepository;
import com.daurenassanbaev.orderservice.dto.OrderDto;
import com.daurenassanbaev.orderservice.dto.OrderReadDto;
import com.daurenassanbaev.orderservice.mapper.OrderMapper;
import com.daurenassanbaev.orderservice.mapper.OrderReadDtoMapper;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaHandler;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor

public class OrderService {
    private final OrderRepository orderRepository;
    private final OrderMapper orderMapper;
    private final OrderReadDtoMapper orderReadDtoMapper;
    private final KafkaTemplate<String, Map<String, Integer>> kafkaTemplate;
    private final KafkaTemplate<String, BigDecimal> amountKafkaTemplate;
    private boolean hasError = false;
    private Integer cartId = -1;


    @Transactional
    public void create(OrderDto orderDto) throws Exception {
        var productId = orderDto.getProductId();
        var quantity = orderDto.getQuantity();
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("productId", productId);
        map.put("quantity", quantity);
        var res1 = kafkaTemplate.send("reduce-product", map).get();
        if (hasError) {
            throw new Exception("Quantity is more");
        } else {
            var res = orderRepository.save(orderMapper.map(orderDto));
            map.clear();
            map.put("userId", orderDto.getUserId());
            var res2 = kafkaTemplate.send("get-cart-id", map);
            if (cartId != -1) {
                map.clear();
                map.put("cartId", cartId);
            }
            hasError = false;
            cartId = -1;
            map.put("orderId", res.getId());
            kafkaTemplate.send("create-cart-item", map).get();
            map.clear();
        }

    }
    @KafkaListener(topics = {"order-errors"})
    @KafkaHandler
    public void check(Integer integer) {
        if (integer == 1) {
            hasError = true;
        }
    }
    @KafkaListener(topics = {"get-orders-amount"})
    @KafkaHandler
    public void getAmounts(List<Integer> list) {
        BigDecimal bigDecimal = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        for (Integer integer : list) {
            var d = findById(integer).get().getTotalPrice();
            bigDecimal = bigDecimal.add(d);
        }
        amountKafkaTemplate.send("total-amount", bigDecimal);
    }
    @KafkaListener(topics = {"give-cart-id"})
    @KafkaHandler
    public void getCartId(List<Integer> list) {
        this.cartId = list.get(0);
    }

    public List<OrderReadDto> findAll() {
        List<Order> orders = orderRepository.findAll();
        return orders.stream().map(orderReadDtoMapper::map).toList();
    }

    public Optional<OrderReadDto> findById(Integer id) {
        Optional<Order> product = orderRepository.findById(id);
        return product.map(orderReadDtoMapper::map);
    }
    @Transactional
    public Optional<OrderReadDto> update(Integer id, OrderReadDto orderReadDto) {
        Optional<Order> foundOrder = orderRepository.findById(id);
        if (foundOrder.isPresent()) {
            Order order = foundOrder.get();
            order.setId(id);
            order.setProductId(orderReadDto.getProductId());
            order.setUserId(orderReadDto.getUserId());
            order.setQuantity(orderReadDto.getQuantity());
            order.setTotalPrice(orderReadDto.getTotalPrice());
            order.setStatus(orderReadDto.getStatus());
            Order product = orderRepository.save(order);
            return Optional.of(orderReadDtoMapper.map(product));
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean delete(Integer id) {
        Optional<Order> order = orderRepository.findById(id);
        if (order.isPresent()) {
            orderRepository.deleteById(id);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}


Please help to solve this error
